# появление блока с задержкой на bootstrap

Tags: html, css, jquery, bootstrap

У меня блок на bootstrap, который появляется автоматически после каждого обновления страницы. Он появляется на 5 секунд. А как сделать так, чтобы еще и появлялся `после` 5-и секунд как страница загрузилась?

`html`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="overlay">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Don`t have an account? Please register</p>
        <div class="mt-3" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
              <a href="{{ url_for('register') }}" style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;">
                  Register
              </a>
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`jquery:`

```
$('#overlay').modal('show');
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlay').modal('hide');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А в чем проблема?

Где-то в корне разместить(сразу после загрузки страницы):

```js
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#overlay').modal('show');
    }, 5000);
});
```